# Show or hide buttons based on div visibility jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have 2 buttons on my page, say button1 and button2. And also a div below it.
Something like below.

```js
    $("#button1,#button2").click(function () {
            $("#div1").toggle("Slow");
    
            if ($("#div1").is(':visible')) {               
                $('#button1').show();
                $('#button2').hide();
            } else {            
                $('#button1').hide();
                $('#button2').show();
            }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divClick">
          <input type="image" id="button1" src="Images/down.png" alt="Submit1" width="25" height="25">
          <br>
          <input type="image" id="button2" src="Images/up.png" alt="Submit2" width="25" height="25">
    </div>
    <div id="div1">
          Welcome!!!
    </div>
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Provide a js fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code no matter what button is pressed so you should split it onto 2 functions or use `$(this)` to refer to the button that has been pressed:

```js
    $("#button1,#button2").click(function () {
        $("#div1").toggle("Slow");
    
        $('input').each(function(){
            //show all button
            $(this).show();
        })

        //hide pressed button
        $(this).hide();
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divClick">
          <input type="image" id="button1" src="Images/down.png" alt="Submit1" width="25" height="25">
          <br>
          <input type="image" id="button2" src="Images/up.png" alt="Submit2" width="25" height="25">
    </div>
    <div id="div1">
          Welcome!!!
    </div>
```

You can see a live example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xv6eorkk/

(you should also hide the button you want at the beginning with css to make it more realistic)

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` and `siblings`.

```js
$("#button1,#button2").click(function(e) {
  $("#div1").toggle("Slow");
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).siblings().show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divClick">
  <input type="image" id="button1" src="Images/down.png" alt="Submit" width="25" height="25">
  <input type="image" id="button2" src="Images/up.png" alt="Submit" width="25" height="25">
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Welcome!!!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="divClick">
   <input type="image" id="button1" class="toggleButton" src="Images/down.png" alt="Submit" width="25" height="25">
   <input type="image" id="button2" class="toggleButton" src="Images/up.png" alt="Submit" width="25" height="25">
</div>
<div id="div1">
          Welcome!!!
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".toggleButton").click(function () {
      $("#div1").toggle("Slow", toggleOnComplete);
    });

function toggleOnComplete(){
   if ($("#div1").is(':visible')) {               
      $('#button1').show();
      $('#button2').hide();
   } else {            
      $('#button1').hide();
      $('#button2').show();
   }
}
```

I added a class in the HTML, because the button have the same functionality.

The thing that goes wrong is that you toggle visibility and immediately ask if the div is visible or not.

While `#div1` is fading away it is still visible as it is performing an animation, so instead you have to call a `function` after the animation is done toggeling.

`.toggle()` knows when it is done, so it also knows when to call the function that you define.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly.

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#button2, #div1").toggle(true);
});
$("#button2").click(function(){
    $("#button2, #div1").toggle(false);
    $("#button1").toggle(true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divClick">
      <input type="image" id="button1" src="Images/down.png" alt="Show" width="25" height="25" style="display:none">
      <input type="image" id="button2" src="Images/up.png" alt="Hide" width="25" height="25">
</div>
<div id="div1">
      Welcome!!!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the initial state using CSS, you can simply call `toggle()` on both buttons and the `#div1` element in a single click event handler:

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('#div1, .button').toggle();
});
```

```css
#button1, #div1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divClick">
  <input type="image" id="button1" src="Images/down.png" alt="Down" width="25" height="25" class="button">
  <input type="image" id="button2" src="Images/up.png" alt="Up" width="25" height="25" class="button">
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Welcome!!!
</div>
```

Note that I added a `button` class to the `input` elements. This can easily be replaced with `input[type="image"]` if you have no control of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button1,#button2').click(function(){
    $("#div1").toggle("Slow"); 
    $(this).toggle("Slow");
    if($(this).attr('id')=='button1'){$('#button2').show();}
    else{$('#button1').show();}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divClick">
      <button type="button" id="button1">Btn 1</button>
      <button type="button" id="button2">Btn 2</button>
   
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div id="div1">
      Welcome!!!
</div>
```